# Communication between separate qml files?

Tags: qt, qml, components, connection

It seems that I have a structure problem in my code, at first I wanted to define some views in different files in `qml`, so I started writing them, and when I wanted to push them in a `StackView`, I had to declare them fist, and "push the id" into the `stack`, but then a friend of mine told I should put them inside component to tell `qt` to only paint them when necessary.

Now I have a structure like this in my `main`:

[image]

Where there is another `StackView`, which is first pushed `login`, then `welcome`, then this one, `home`. where I push the actual views into the `body`

[image]

I needed some pop up in the app, launched by some views in the `body`, so I putted that `popupLoader` to be able to darken all the screen like this:

[image]

But then I started having problem with communication between `qml` files, I made alias `popup`, so I could listen to `popup` signals like this inside views of the `body`:

[image]

And it worked just fine, but now I'm having problems listening to signals the other way round, from the `views` sending data to the `popups`, with `alerts` defined this way in the `main`, it does not work:

[image]

But this way it does work:

[image]

I have also tried using the same tecnique with alias as before, but I did not how to make it:

[image]

What to do you think? Can you explain me what's behind the curtains with those components? how would you achieve this? without using the C side

thanks in advance 
:D

Comment: Why you post images instead of text?

Comment: because is easier to see, at least in some, in the second picture, there are 384 lines of code

Comment: It will be a problem if someone want to copy the code. Also I advice you to minimise it to focus only on the problem. Most likely  the problem will be solved since this process.